# Connect to a remote database server instead of localhost

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to my WAMP sever by using its IP address in my LAN. So far I have written the following code, and I don't understand why it does not establish the connection.

```
public class DBConnect {    
    public static Connection connect()
    {
        Connection con=null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/employee101?","root","");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("inter.DBConnect.connect()");
        }
        return con;
    }    
}
```

Comment: What sort of Exception is occurring?  Try printing e's message or stack trace.

Comment: Please don't swallow exceptions. Either let them bubble up, wrap them, or at the very minimum, log the actual exception (e.g. `e.printStackTrace()`, or better yet, using a logging library).

Answer (score 2):

The `root` mysql account is configured to only allow a connection from the PC running the MySQL Server. For obvious security reasons.

I suggest you go to the WAMPServer machine and login to MySQL as root, then create a new account, that is NOT a Super User account and HAS password. Using `phpMyAdmin` for this is probably easiest.

Then configure the domain for this account to allow connections from your network only (192.168.1) note only 3 of the 4 quartiles used will allow access from any IP in your network, but only from within your network. Allocate only the required privileges on the specific databases required, to the new account.

Then use this new account in your Java code.